# Python requests - how to save a gif scraped with requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

At the moment, I have the following code:

```
import requests


with open("location.gif", "wb") as f:
    f.write(requests.get(url).content)
```

This creates the "location.gif" file, but opening the file shows me no image and when trying to send it to someone it tells me it's not a valid file. How should I save the gif?